# SQL group by date difference with previous row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I looking for some grouping using datetime daily rows to build date range intervals

My table is something like:

```
id | A  | B  | Date
1  | 1  | 2  | 1/10/2010
2  | 1  | 2  | 2/10/2010
3  | 1  | 2  | 3/10/2010
4  | 1  | 3  | 4/10/2010
5  | 1  | 3  | 5/10/2010
6  | 1  | 2  | 6/10/2010
7  | 1  | 2  | 7/10/2010
8  | 1  | 2  | 8/10/2010
```

My first try was:

```
SELECT A, B, MIN(DATE), MAX(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY A, B
```

So after group by A, B and use min and max with date on my select, I get invalid results due the repetition of B = 2.

```
     A    B   Date                 A  B   min(Date)  max(Date)
1  | 1  | 2  | 1/10/2010           1  2 | 1/10/2010  8/10/2010
2  | 1  | 2  | 2/10/2010  Invalid
3  | 1  | 2  | 3/10/2010  ------->
6  | 1  | 2  | 6/10/2010
7  | 1  | 2  | 7/10/2010
8  | 1  | 2  | 8/10/2010
```

I'm looking for how to calculate the third member of the group by...
So the expected intervals results:

```
     A    B   Start Date    End Date 
.. | 1  | 2 | 1/10/2010  | 3/10/2010
.. | 1  | 3 | 4/10/2010  | 5/10/2010 
.. | 1  | 2 | 6/10/2010  | 8/10/2010
```

I need to support SQL Server 2008

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What query did you try? Actually, the solution in your link (on looking at it) is entirely different from what you want. This seems like a standard "islands and gaps" issue - I would suggest searching for that and seeing if you come up with any solutions.

Comment: You are right. I have removed the link

Answer (score 2):

The following is an easy way to deal with "islands and gaps" where you need to find gaps in consecutive dates:

```
SELECT A, B, StartDate = MIN([Date]), EndDate = MAX([Date])
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        RN = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Date]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM myTable
) AS T
GROUP BY A, B, RN;
```

To break it down into slightly simpler-to-understand logic: you assign each date a number (`DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Date])` here) and each date a row number (partitioned by A and B here), then any time there's a gap in the dates, the difference between those two will change.

There are a variety of resources you can use to understand different approaches to "islands and gaps" problems. Here is one that might help you with tackling other varieties of this in the future: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/